# Auto-implemented properties and additional function

Tags: c#

Is there a way to do something like this in C#:

```
public class Class2 {
 public string PropertyName1 { get 
   {
         return this; //i mean "PropertyName1"
   }
   set {
       this = value;
       DoAdditionalFunction();
   }
}
```

Because I need to call additional function in the "set" I need to have an extra private field like

```
private string _propertyName1;
 public string PropertyName1 { get 
   {
         return _propertyName1;
   }
   set {
       _propertyName1= value;
       DoAdditionalFunction();
   }
```

I don't want to use additional property like _propertyName1. Is there a way to accomplish this or any best practices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - if you need *any* behaviour other than the most trivial "set a field, return the field value", you need to write "full" properties. Automatically implemented properties are *only* a shorthand for trivial properties.

Note that you haven't really got an "extra" private field, in terms of the actual contents of an object - it's just that you're explicitly declaring the private field instead of letting the compiler do it for you as part of the automatically implemented property.

(It's not clear what your first property is trying to do - setting `this` in a class is invalid, and you can't return `this` from a property of type string unless you've got a conversion *to* string...)